How to resolve FastAPI StaticFiles route with deep routes
My FastApi server is configured with static route,
app.include_router(api)
app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory=script_dir,html=True), name="static")

In static directory I have vuetify/vite dist files.
I want all routes except in "api" to be entertained by static route. The routes that are being catched by it correctly but only till 2 levels i.e following works
http://localhost/tables/vm
but following give 'Not Found'
http://localhost/tables/vm/add
tried changing route positions, but it completely stop routes working.

what do you have in other routes? Maybe they need deeper pattern or more universal patter which can match to deeper path - and which doesn't treats ../.. in path as next level.
